# django how to save current user from views.py

Tags: django

I have a table called items

```
office_id , sem ,sy ,remarks, recorded_by
```

And table called customuser

```
userid, password, email
```

How can i save the current user's userid here at table items > recorded_by

for now this is my **views.py**

```
class Add(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
form_class = CreateForm
model = ClearanceItem
template_name = 'clearance/add.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.recorded_by= self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? Looks like your code is almost the same as in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the object before committing it to the database, update the `recorded_by` attribute, and then commit it to the database.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.recorded_by = self.request.user
    instance.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```